# passing selected button value from fb messenger to dialog flow

Tags: facebook-messenger, dialogflow-es

I am failing to understand the simple passing of parameters to and fro via webhook. i am trying to build a simple bot using dialog flow and fb messenger. i have requirement to show two buttons to the end user to pick a cake type. i am able to show the options using the below custom response:

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "template",
      "payload": {
        "template_type": "button",
        "text": "What kind of cake would you like?",
        "buttons": [
          {
            "type": "postback",
            "payload": "witheggs",
            "title": "Contain Eggs"
          },
          {
            "type": "postback",
            "payload": "noeggs",
            "title": "Eggless"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

once user tap one of the two buttons then how do i set it to some variable in dialog flow and then ask next set of question?

Answer (score 4):

I guess you're missing few steps here. Before, I explain you what to do, be sure to know what a `postback` is! `Postback`, when tapped, the text is sent as a user query to dialogflow.com.

Step-1: I created an intent with custom payload as follows:

[image]

Step-2: Now, I created a new intent where I have entered user says as `noeggs` which is of type `postback` & payload as `noeggs` the in previous image.

[image]

Step-3: Save & test it in FB Messenger.

[image]

So basically, what has happened here is, when you click on Eggless button, postback as `noeggs` is sent as user query to dialogflow.com where there is an intent which matches user says with `noeggs` & sends response back.