# postback users action in hangout chat bot

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-hangouts

I am trying to ask users feedback on bot responses however it's not working or no response

Steps-

1. I created an intent with custom payload as follows
2. created a new intent where I have entered user says as "Yes" which is of type postback & payload as "Yes"

My logic is-

- When users click on Yes button,
- postback as Yes is sent as user query to dialogflow.com
- where there is an intent which matches user says with Yes & sends a response back.

```js
{
  "hangouts": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "template",
      "payload": {
        "template_type": "button",
        "text": "Was this article helpful?",
        "buttons": [
          {
            "type": "postback",
            "payload": "Yes",
            "title": "Yes"
          },
          {
            "type": "postback",
            "payload": "NO",
            "title": "No"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have indicated it is "not working or no reply". What happens when you try this? Do you have any logs showing this? The more detailed information you can provide, the better.

Comment: I am not getting any error in the hangout - POPUP says "bot not responding"

Comment: How are you generating the JSON? Are there any errors in Dialogflow's logs or in your fulfillment's logs?

Comment: @Prisoner No error message in  Dialogflow's logs
I have tried following SO Link  logics (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48200978/passing-selected-button-value-from-fb-messenger-to-dialog-flow) is any better method to achieve my requirement 

To ask users feedback on Bot response want to show two buttons based on the user click (postback )post the value in response then follow up  intent will show the response